# Nginx rewrite rule for CDN

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am struggling with converting an Apache rewrite rule to Nginx.

The rule lives inside `WEBROOT/cdn/.htacces` and reads:

`RewriteRule ^[0-9]{1,6}/(.*)$ ../$1 [PT]`

The goal of it is to take a URL like:
`http://...com/cdn/123123/some/other/path.css` and load the file located in `http://...com/some/other/path.css`.

I've tried different variations on the theme of:

`location /cdn {
        rewrite "^/[0-9]{1,6}/(.*)$" ../$1;
}`

I am ending up with 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

`location ^~ /cdn {
        rewrite "^/cdn/[0-9]{1,6}/(.*)$" /$1 break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but think your problem is right at the beginning of your location block:

```
location /cdn
```

I think if you try something like this:

```
location ^/cdn/(.*)
```

you'll get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you, Roger. I tried it, with as per above, and with a few minor variations without luck.